# How to view image from android gallery using Image URI

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am developing an app that saves an image to gallery. I want use a button, when clicked to show that image. I have tried few steps and seems its not working. I have just started coding in android. So searching in Google also has some limitations as I dont have great idea on what to search to get the exact solution. Your help would be highly appreciated

```
tv_view.setOnClickListener 
{ startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,photoURI ))}
```

I am able to share the image using the same photoURI. here is the code , I used the following code

```
    tv_share.setOnClickListener {                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI)
                                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);//added
                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Would you like to share this image now?"))

                            }
```

Comment: I have 2 buttons, one that enable users to view the saved image and another one is to share the same image ( Sharing is working fine), But to view image, when clicked it opens a blank dark screen with a loader icon. In short, my view image is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using the following code

```
tv_view.setOnClickListener {
                                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                intent.data = photoURI
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                startActivity(intent)
                            }
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `startActivity` use `startActivityforResult` and handle the result accordingly , for example, show that image in a imageview.

Comment: So you have the image and you just want to display the image?

Answer (score 0):

use FRESCO, more info here -> https://frescolib.org/docs/index.html.